# Openpyxl not found in Pycharm

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am new to programming Python using Pycharm.  I would like to access **openpyxl** (which I installed) but get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in 
do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

This is probably a very simple problem but I just don't know how to proceed.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 14):

In the `pycharm`, go to `File`->`settings`->`project Interpreter`
Then click the right top corner `+` button you will get pop up window to install packages. Then search for `openpyxl` you will get the latest package. Then click `Install package` to install it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer solved my problem. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly how user5777975 explained however on some systems "Project Interpreter" is named "Python Interpreter" and the interface is slightly different.

So:

In the pycharm, go to File->settings->Python Interpreter Then click the + button ion the top left of the table of installed packages, you will get pop up window to install packages. Then search for openpyxl and you will get the latest package (default option). Then click Install package to install it. You will get notification if successful.

Answer (score 0):

go to terminal and type "pip install openpyxl"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).